# cosmos DB query how to exclude dictionary that contains certain item

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Lets say I have 3 records in cosmos db like following - how do I write a query to exclude second record? first one is easy `c.BusinessContext != null` but I could not find a way to exclude second record.

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.BusinessContext['value']
FROM c
where c.BusinessContext != null
and NOT (c.BusinessContext['value'] = '')
```

does not work

```json
{
   "BusinessContext": null
}

{
  "BusinessContext": {"value" : ""}
}

{
  "BusinessContext": { "key1": "value1", "key2" : "value2"}]
}
```

Comment: Not sure why your data model is the way it is: every document represents `BusinessContext` in a different way. The 2nd doc has `value` as a key, where in the 3rd doc it's a key/value pair. You should have all documents consistent. At this point, your query is going to have to compensate for multiple variants of content, due to these inconsistencies. Also: why do you need a `null` value for `BusinessContext`, vs just not having the property when there's nothing to represent in its value?